# Create a stream from a bitmap on Windows Runtime

Tags: c#, windows-8, stream, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

I would like to create a stream from a bitmap. First I did it with :

```
Stream imgStream = typeof(Main).GetTypeInfo().Assembly.GetManifestResourceStream("ApplicationBlockBase.Assets.testimage.jpg");
```

But now I need to create a Stream from a local image. Do you have any ideas?

Thanks for your time, regards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let me know it this works or not.

```
StorageFile imageFile = await (await Windows.ApplicationModel.Package.Current.InstalledLocation.GetFolderAsync("Assets")).GetFileAsync("testimage.jpg");
Stream imgStream = await imageFile.OpenStreamForReadAsync();
```

Comment: I tried, and there is an error which is :
"Can't convert type 'Windows.Foundaton.IAsyncOperation<Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream>' to 'System.IO.Stream';

I tried to cast (STREAM) and doesn't work too

Comment: Sorry for i take some time to test thing in my own too. First, may be i explained bad, because i would like to get an image from "local" installation and not asset. 
Now when i try to get the image i have  (Exception de HRESULT : 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED)).

I try this too :
                        var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ms-appdata:///local/image.jpg");
                        //StorageFile filed = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("ms-appdata:///local/image.jpg");

Comment: Thanks its ok i just need to not use "ms-appdate:///" but just :
StorageFile filed = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("image.jpg"‌​);